# Neo4j: Find Person who acted in and directed any movies

Tags: neo4j, cypher, match, movie

I want to display all Person who act as well as direct a movie. It does not matter if the person direct a movie but does not act in the movie. As long as there are edges ACTED_IN and DIRECTED exist on a node, the query will display the result.

I have tried several Cypher queries. This one I believe show the nearest result I intend to:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE exists( (p)-[:DIRECTED]->() )
RETURN distinct *
```

Now, the issue is, one of the result shows "James Marshall" ACTED_IN "A Few Good Men" but he also DIRECTED two different movies which are "Ninja Assasin" and "V for Vendetta".

My current outcome only display "James Marshall" ACTED_IN "A Few Good Men" and does not show the other two movies he DIRECTED. So, how can I improve my Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first match on persons that have the relationships you need (this will be a degree check), then MATCH on the pattern using both relationships at once (which would be an OR match for the relationships in question otherwise):

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE (p)-[:ACTED_IN]->() AND (p)-[:DIRECTED->()
MATCH path = (p)-[:ACTED_IN | DIRECTED]->(m:Movie)
RETURN path
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution in this [post](https://community.neo4j.com/t/exercise-4-11-in-intro-neo4j-exercises/16402/5)

The key point is to add another relationships in the other way around (right to the left to the movie), and then add in the WHERE clause the condition.

> MATCH (a1:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a2:Person)
> WHERE exists( (a2)-[:DIRECTED]->(m) ) RETURN  a2, m

[image: Result of the query]

Comment: Sam result: `MATCH (p1:Person)-[:DIRECTED]->(m:Movie), (p2:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie) 
WHERE p1=p2 RETURN p1, m, p2;`

Comment: Same: 
MATCH (p)-[a:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[d:DIRECTED]-(p) 
RETURN p,a,d,m